# Why don't countries use an auction to issue residency visas?

Tags: immigration

In the US there is a long-standing issue with H1B (work) visas, where there's many more applicants than free spots, which results in a sort of lottery on who gets to immigrate to the US. Likewise the diversity lottery only accepts 0.5% of  applicants because there are simply far too many people willing to immigrate to the US.

But why rely on lotteries to decide who gets to immigrate? Why not simply auction-off every single long-term residency visa using a second-price auction or a Dutch auction? This could allow the country to completely eliminate all rules on who is allowed to immigrate (except for basic things like the lack of criminal records) and simply rely on the free market to decide which people are currently in demand by the economy.  Likewise it would be impossible for companies to abuse the system to invite underpaid workers as only the most valuable employees would make the cut.

Or perhaps there are already countries which use auctions to decide their immigration policy?

Comment: well there are as well fixed amounts of money for business immigration, but I get the point. Interesting question.

Comment: @JDoe if you have a straight-up auction system companies could fire all immigration lawyers (which are very expensive) and pay the money directly, with a guaranteed result or refund. You could likewise auction off residency visa extensions and eliminate the need to provide documents justifying the continuing need to stay in the country.

Comment: This is phrased in a way that suggests it is representing a particular point of view, and so off-topic.

Comment: Diversity visa's whole purpose would be negated by an auction; unless held per-country.

Comment: @user4012 can be per country as well. Anything's better than random.

Comment: What would that achieve? Certainly not a beneficial mix of people or fairness towards workers (locals and migrants alike). It would also outsource policy-making to the richest industries, which is problematic. Importantly, schemes allowing underpaid workers, where they exist, are not “abuses” of the system, they are deliberate and often go hand-in-hand with very restrictive/hostile policies regarding settlement (cf. the Swiss A permit, the French *travailleur saisonnier*/OMI visas). The employers benefitting from them have lobbyists too.

Comment: @Relaxed non-immigrant/non-extendable visas can function just they way they do now. But for permanent settlement visas companies are usually required to prove they can't hire an equivalent local for the same salary. Lots of bureaucracy, paperwork and lawyers involved, which an auction would easily get rid of.

Comment: @JonathanReez Maybe, but that only strengthens my points: To the extent that it is a problem, competition from underpaid migrants would be just as bad. In fact, temporary visas and ties to an employer are a big part of the problem here: it gives employers additional leverage. And employers paying good money for a sponsorship would want some guarantees, compounding the problem further. In a nutshell, there is no constituency for an auction, which problems does it solve?

Comment: @Relaxed Employers already waste tens of thousands of dollars on each H1B, as there's a lot of paperwork and waiting time to go through. Paying the money directly to the government won't change the status quo. And I'm not sure how employers could possibly obtain guarantees from highly paid employees? If they go too far they'll ruin their reputation and nobody would work for them in the future. Again, assuming that the auction system would only bring in people earning 150k+$ per year to the US, as it won't be too economical for employees of low value.

Comment: @JonathanReez But the H1B is a temporary worker visa, so what are we talking about? And it's precisely one of those that suffers from the problem I pointed out: It ties the person to an employer. Some (but not all) employers might be fine with an auction but they would need some other guarantee instead. The fact that it would be difficult under your scheme is a weakness from their point of view and they certainly have some influence on the design of the system. Again, which problem does an auction solve for them (or anybody else)?

Comment: @Relaxed you can transition from an H1B to a Green Card, so it's effectively a settlement visa. Truly temporary visas like the J1 have no route to settlement. The problem right now is that there's a lot of bureaucracy, the best people don't necessarily get a visa and you can only apply once a year. In EU countries there is likewise a problem with waiting times, the necessity to conduct a market labour test, lots of documents to prepare, etc. Auctioning and immediately issuing visas to winners would completely remove all bottlenecks.

Comment: @JonathanReez Transitioning is not trivial or immediate, it makes no sense to call it a settlement visa, effectively or otherwise. In this particular case, a simple fix for many problems is to let workers come more easily or switch jobs and settle without restriction. That's also better for the economy and workers in general. But that's no good for their sponsors (whether through an auction or otherwise), hence the status quo. In the EU, the rules actually differ quite a lot but the same logic holds: Current systems result from many compromises, nobody has any interest in an auction system.

Comment: @JonathanReez You said that you're basing your point on the premise that "Anything's better than random", but I don't think that can be taken for granted. (True, transparent) randomness has the twin advantages of both fairness and a perception of fairness (or at least a version of "fairness" that doesn't take into account need or means -- perhaps fair is a bad term for me to use).

Comment: @JonathanReez there are two answers here already and you've added a bounty is there something specific that these answers are not covering?

Comment: @SteveSmith offcii statements from government officials about the idea or examples of existing implementations

Answer (score 3):

> Why not simply auction-off every single long-term residency visa using a second-price auction or a Dutch auction?

In general this may be seen as sending out the wrong message i.e. people can buy their way into the US. under current law immigrant workers can get a green card and then apply for citizen ship in five years. This is potentially very easy to play for example a person could pay the company to bid more and get themselves into the country and hence are on their way to citizenship.

Many companies would not be able to pay the market price. so instead of a range of companies getting getting a small number immigrant workers each a small handful of probably larger companies that can afford to pay will get a larger number of immigrant workers. This could really hit smaller businesses

> it would be impossible for companies to abuse the system to invite underpaid workers

A reason for allowing immigration is exactly this, to ensure that companies can gain access to cheap labour and so that there is a certain labour surplus (which keeps the price of labour down)

> This could allow the country to completely eliminate all rules on who is allowed to immigrate

Perhaps, but it would simply require a whole range of other laws about how bidding works, what companies can bid, people not buying their way in and so on. Also their may be emigration routes not suited to this kind of approach (i.e. where their is no company to bid).

There may be a range of other issues depending on how this is implemented but I think that these are the main consideration with this policy.

Comment: Well, people can already buy their way into the US through investor visas, so that's nothing new. And small businesses are already suffering because it costs a lot of money to bring someone into the country using the H1B system (lawyers, application fees, etc).

Comment: @JonathanReez yes but they have to invest or be in the process of investing"$1 million (or $500,000 in targeted employment areas) in a new commercial enterprise that will benefit the U.S. economy and create at least 10 full-time positions" note the full time jobs, it isn't just pay and get in.  You are right about about the expense, sources vary on what exactly the cost is but it shouldn't be so bad that it would be impossible for a small business (especially as they get discounts)

Comment: If you have a few million dollars nothing stops you from opening a couple of restaurants in the US for the sake of hiring 10 employees. The US doesn't force you to start a *successful* - you might as well completely lose your initial investment just to get a visa. Hence it's effectively a way to pay your way into the US.

Answer (score 2):

- It seems like you want the companies to pay for this. They probably do not want to do that, so I would expect a certain amount of pressure for politicians bringing such a proposal forward.
- If the individual should pay for it, then you might get situations where people who have a lot of money but no income immigrate, which is generally not what you want to achieve with work visas.
- The believe that the invisible hand of the market magically results in optimal outcomes is not universally accepted.
- Not everyone agrees that economic reasons are the only valid reasons to allow permanent residency. That is why the diversity lottery or the possibility for asylum or refuge exist, or why family members of residents may apply for residency.
- Additionally, some value work that is done outside of highly profitable industries. Sure you want bankers and engineers to immigrate, but some might also value professors, artists, or religious workers.

Comment: Companies already waste tens of thousands of dollars on getting each H1B employee (lawyers, application fees, etc) into the country, with the result not guaranteed under the current system. And you can have sub-lotteries for universities so that they have the chance to hire too.

Comment: @JonathanReez: There is a vast difference between spending a known amount for a known uncertainty of getting the visum, and knowing that you'll get into a bidding war with companies whose budgets far surpass yours. It's effectively going to ensure that foreign workers are only available to the largest corporations. Even if you put things up for auction, the companies will still initially spend the money in doing the needed paperwork - the opposite would mean that they bid on a visum before they've even ascertained that the applicant can be hired/allowed into the country.

Comment: @Flater high skilled foreign workers are already pretty much limited to companies with deep pockets, as it's very expensive to get through the hurdles of visa bureaucracy and it usually takes 6+ months to finish the process. Why pay $50k to a lawyer when you can just pay that to the government and get a guaranteed result? And in my proposal absolutely no paperwork would be required beyond a criminal check.